# Use Select to Join two tables, Show only a few columns and also have a between criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql

I googled and searched this place but not an answer I could Find because what others have was different.

```
USE TestDatabase
Select Firstname,Lastname,Salary From Employee as E 
Join JobTitle as J
on E.JobTitleID = J.JobTitleID

WHERE Salary 
BETWEEN $25000.00 AND $50000.00
```

This works but I am trying to show two columns from JobTitle Table and I don't either know what words to search or Google and can't not find a simple answer. Can anyone help must be simple for some but I am confused. I am using server 2008 t-sql for school

Comment: what are the columns you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the alias of the table `JobTitle` which is `J` to select any extra columns you want to select

```
Select Firstname, Lastname, Salary, 
   j.Field1, j.Field2 ... -- and other fields you want to select here
From Employee as E 
Join JobTitle as J
on E.JobTitleID = J.JobTitleID

WHERE Salary 
BETWEEN $25000.00 AND $50000.00
```

Comment: It worked just fine thank you very muchbut JobTitle was the Table name that was what confused me. I could not search or Google this and I have 5 minutes remaining before I can accept the answer. Do I select answer two because of the mistake?

Comment: Well thank you all they were all the same answer and worked so God Bless you all thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the alias to set who is the table you're using to the field.

```
Select
    E.Firstname,E.Lastname,E.Salary,
    j.JobTitle, j.Otherfieldyouwanttoselect
From Employee as E Join JobTitle as J on E.JobTitleID = J.JobTitleID
WHERE
    Salary BETWEEN $25000.00 AND $50000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select E.Firstname, E.Lastname, E.Salary, J.Column1, J.Column2
    From Employee as E 
        Join JobTitle as J
            on E.JobTitleID = J.JobTitleID
    WHERE E.Salary BETWEEN $25000.00 AND $50000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this ?

```
USE TestDatabase
Select Firstname,Lastname,Salary,J.YourcolumnfromJobTitle  From Employee as E 
Join JobTitle as J
on E.JobTitleID = J.JobTitleID

WHERE Salary 
BETWEEN $25000.00 AND $50000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use alias name for both table like this:

```
USE TestDatabase
Select E.Firstname,E.Lastname,E.Salary,J.Column1,j.Column2 From Employee as E 
Join JobTitle as J
on E.JobTitleID = J.JobTitleID

WHERE E.Salary 
BETWEEN $25000.00 AND $50000.00
```